# OpenGL Vertex Buffer incorrect render

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, vbo

I'm having a bit of an odd problem. I'm trying to render some data with OpenGL on my Windows system. I found a set of tutorials at opengl-tutorial.org which were written for OpenGL 3.3. As my laptop (where I do a great deal of developing) only supports OpenGL 2.1, I proceeded to download the OpenGL 2.1 port of the tutorial. I messed around with it a bit, adding features and refactoring it for scalability, but noticed something odd. Whenever I rendered my data with Vertex Buffer Objects, I got a rather incorrect representation of my data. This is shown below.
http://www.majhost.com/gallery/DagonEcelstraun/Others/HelpNeeded/badrender.png
However, when I specify my data using glVertex3fv and such, I get a much nicer result, again shown below.
http://www.majhost.com/gallery/DagonEcelstraun/Others/HelpNeeded/goodrender.png
The problem occurs both on my Windows 8.1 laptop with Intel i3 integrated graphics and on my Windows 7 desktop with its nVidia GTX 660, so it's not a hardware problem. Does anyone know what may be the issue here?

Loading mesh data:

```
const aiScene *scene = aiImportFile( sName.c_str(), 
aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_MaxQuality | aiProcess_FlipUVs );
const aiMesh *mesh = scene->mMeshes[0];
for( int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++ ) {
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mVertices[i][0] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mVertices[i][1] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mVertices[i][2] );

    meshData.push_back( mesh->mNormals[i][0] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mNormals[i][1] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mNormals[i][2] );

    meshData.push_back( mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i][0] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i][1] );
    meshData.push_back( 0 );

    meshData.push_back( mesh->mTangents[i][0] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mTangents[i][1] );
    meshData.push_back( mesh->mTangents[i][2] );
}

for( int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        indices.push_back( mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[j] );
    }
}
```

Sending data to the graphics card for the first time (called right after previous code):

```
glGenBuffers( 1, &glVertData );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glVertData );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.size() * sizeof( GLfloat ), &meshData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );

// Generate a buffer for the indices as well
glGenBuffers( 1, &glIndexes );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, glIndexes );
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Rendering the mesh:

```
//Tell the shader to use our data
//bindVerts, bindUvs, bindNorms, and bindTangents refer to attribute variables in my shader
//vertexPosition_modelspace, vertexUV, vertexNormal_modelspace, and vertexTangent_modelspace, respectively.
this->verts = bindVerts;
this->uvs = bindUvs;
this->norms = bindNorms;
this->tangents = bindTangents;
glEnableVertexAttribArray( verts );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( uvs );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( norms );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( tangents );

//Specify how the graphics card should decode our data
// 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, glVertData );
glVertexAttribPointer( verts, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, (void*) 0 );

// 2nd attribute buffer : normals
glVertexAttribPointer( norms, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, (void*) 3 ); 

//3rd attribute buffer : UVs
glVertexAttribPointer( uvs, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, (void*) 6 );

//4th attribute buffer: tangents
glVertexAttribPointer( tangents, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 12, (void*) 9 );

// Index buffer
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, glIndexes );

//rendering the mesh with VBOs:
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*) 0 );

//specifying the vertex data individually:
glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
int ind;
for( int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++ ) {
    ind = indices[i] * 12;
    glNormal3fv( &meshData[ind + 3] );
    glTexCoord2fv( &meshData[ind + 6] );
    glVertex3fv( &meshData[ind] );
}
glEnd();

//clean up after the render
glDisableVertexAttribArray( verts );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( uvs );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( norms );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( tangents );
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 130

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
//it doesn't work, so we'll just get rid of it
attribute vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
attribute vec3 vertexUV;
attribute vec3 vertexNormal_modelspace;
attribute vec3 vertexTangent_modelspace;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;
out vec3 Position_worldspace;
out vec3 Normal_cameraspace;
out vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
out vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;
out vec4 ShadowCoord;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform vec3 LightInvDirection_worldspace;
uniform mat4 DepthBiasMVP;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;

attribute vec3 vTangent;

void main() {
    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4( vertexPosition_modelspace, 1 );

    ShadowCoord = DepthBiasMVP *  vec4( vertexPosition_modelspace, 0 );

    // Position of the vertex, in worldspace : M * position
    Position_worldspace = ( M * vec4( vertexPosition_modelspace, 0 ) ).xyz;

    // Vector that goes from the vertex to the camera, in camera space.
    // In camera space, the camera is at the origin (0,0,0).
    EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3( 0, 0, 0 ) - ( V * M *  vec4(         vertexPosition_modelspace, 0 ) ).xyz;

    // Vector that goes from the vertex to the light, in camera space
    LightDirection_cameraspace = ( V * vec4( LightInvDirection_worldspace, 0 ) ).xyz;

    // UV of the vertex. No special space for this one.
    UV = vertexUV.st;

    // Normal of the the vertex, in camera space
    // Only correct if ModelMatrix does not scale the model ! Use its inverse transpose if not.
    Normal_cameraspace = ( V * M * vec4( vertexNormal_modelspace.xyz, 0 ) ).xyz; 
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 130

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec2 UV;
in vec3 Position_worldspace;
in vec3 Normal_cameraspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
in vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;
in vec4 ShadowCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D diffuse;
uniform mat4 MV;
uniform vec3 LightPosition_worldspace;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;
//uniform int shadowLevel;  //0 is no shadow, 1 is hard shadows, 2 is soft shadows, 3 is PCSS

// Returns a random number based on a vec3 and an int.
float random( vec3 seed, int i ) {
    vec4 seed4 = vec4( seed, i );           
    float dot_product = dot( seed4, vec4( 12.9898, 78.233, 45.164, 94.673 ) );
    return fract( sin( dot_product ) * 43758.5453 );
}

int mod( int a, int b ) {
    return a - (a / b);
}

void main() {
    int shadowLevel = 1;    //let's just do hard shadows
    // Light emission properties
    vec3 LightColor = vec3( 1, 1, 1 );
    float LightPower = 1.0f;

    // Material properties
    vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture( diffuse, UV ).rgb;
    vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3( 0.3, 0.3, 0.3 );

    vec3 n = normalize( Normal_cameraspace );
    vec3 l = normalize( LightDirection_cameraspace );
    float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n, l ), 0.2, 1 );

    // Eye vector (towards the camera)
    vec3 E = normalize( EyeDirection_cameraspace );
    // Direction in which the triangle reflects the light
    vec3 R = reflect( -l, n );
    // Cosine of the angle between the Eye vector and the Reflect vector,
    // clamped to 0
    //  - Looking into the reflection -> 1
    //  - Looking elsewhere -> < 1
    float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E, R ), 0, 1 );

    float visibility = 1.0;

    //variable bias
    float bias = 0.005 * tan( acos( cosTheta ) );
    bias = clamp( bias, 0, 0.01 );

    // dFragment to the light
    float dFragment = ( ShadowCoord.z-bias ) / ShadowCoord.w;
    float dBlocker = 0;
    float penumbra = 1;
    float wLight = 5.0;

    if( shadowLevel == 3 ) {
        // Sample the shadow map 8 times
        float count = 0;
        float temp;
        float centerBlocker = texture( shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xy).r;
        float scale = (wLight * (dFragment - centerBlocker)) / dFragment;
        for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {    
            temp = texture( shadowMap, ShadowCoord.xy + (scale * poissonDisk( i ) / 50.0) ).r;
            if( temp < dFragment ) {
                dBlocker += temp;
                count += 1;    
            }
        }

        if( count > 0 ) {
            dBlocker /= count;
            penumbra = wLight * (dFragment - dBlocker) / dFragment;
        }
    }

    if( shadowLevel == 1 ) {
        if( texture( shadowMap,  ShadowCoord.xy).r < dFragment ) {
            visibility -= 0.8;
        }
    } else if( shadowLevel > 1 ) {
        float iterations = 32;
        float sub = 0.8f / iterations;
        for( int i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ) {
            int index = mod( int( 32.0 * random( gl_FragCoord.xyy, i ) ), 32 );
            if( texture( shadowMap,  ShadowCoord.xy + (penumbra * poissonDisk( index ) / 250.0) ).r < dFragment ) {
                visibility -= sub;
            }
        }
    }
    visibility = min( visibility, cosTheta );
    //MaterialDiffuseColor = vec3( 0.8, 0.8, 0.8 );
    fragColor.rgb = MaterialAmbientColor +
        visibility * MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower +
        visibility * MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow( cosAlpha, 5             );
}
```

Note that poissonDisk( int ind ) returns a vec2 with a magnitude of no more than 1 which is in a poisson disk distribution. Even though I'm using shader version 130, I used a function and not an array because the array runs rather slowly on my laptop.

I do bind that shader before I do any rendering. I also make sure to upload the correct variables to all of my uniforms, but I didn't show that to save space since I know it's working correctly.

Does anyone know what's causing this incorrect render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, stop drawing the VBO using `GL_LINES`. Use the same primitive mode for immediate mode and VBO drawing.

Also, since when is 3*4 = 3? The address (offset) in your VBO vertex pointers should be the number of elements multiplied by the size of the data type when using an interleaved data structure. `GL_FLOAT` is 4 bytes, if you have a 3-component vertex position this means that the offset to the next field in your VBO is 3*4 = `(void *)12`, not `(void *)3`. This process must continue for each additional vertex array pointer, they all use incorrect offsets.

Likewise, the stride of your VBO should be 12 * sizeof (GLfloat) = 48, not 12.

Comment: I did that and got a number of errors from nvoglv32.dll, which some quick googling revealed as my nVidia card's OpenGL driver. Specifically, it told me that it was having trouble reading from location 0x00000000. Some quick debugging revealed the problem to be in Mesh::draw(), when I call glDrawElements. I also found that I was trying to send vertex positions, normals, tangents, and UVs to location 0. Once I fixed that, it worked wonderfully. Thank you!